# msmdsrv.exe is taking 1.5 GB of memory?

Tags: windows, memory, process

I have a windows server and this server has 4 GB of memory. But the msmdsrv.exe is taking 1.5 GB of memory.  What is that, and why is it doing this?  How can I make it stop?

This is a production server.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick google shows that `msmdsrv` is SQL Server Analytics Server. So, the short answer is: You don't. I assume you are doing something with SSAS, which means that you want it to have memory allocated.

4GB isn't really very much though - *especially* for anything running SQL Server or its related services.

Comment: Yeah, this is another case of "I want my server to waste memory rather than using it efficiently". We see a lot of those.

Comment: Or it's another case of "My server is using resources and I have no idea whether or not that's normal but I'm pretty sure I don't want it to because I have no idea of what I'm looking at".